# During build/deploy, how do I get around Nuget packages that only copied files?

Tags: msbuild, twitter-bootstrap, less, nuget, nuget-package

### Background

I have an MVC3 project to which I added the *Twitter.Bootstrap.Less* Nuget package.

To my knowledge, all this did was copy the appropriate JavaScript / LESS files into their appropriate directories.

However, when I now run this through my build/deploy process onto my dev server, MSBuild doesn't copy the /Content/less folder to my production server as part of deployment package.

**My build server doesn't have an internet connection, so unfortunately [using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages#Using_NuGet_without_committing_packages_to_source_control) isn't an option.**

### Question

How do I get MSBuild to deploy these files? Or do I need to copy the files, uninstall the nuget package, and manually copy them back in?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your own internal NuGet package source. That would be internal to your network and mean the build server could pickup the NuGet packages without an internet connection.

E.g. On the server, copy the packages you need to a folder and setup a package feed to that folder for the build server to use.

See:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds